# Is Falcor suitable for dynamic data applications?

Tags: falcor

I went through the online Falcor videos and tutorials and it sounds very interesting. I am trying to determine if this would be a good fit for our application needs. Somewhere in the presentation I heard that it is very well suited for fairly static application, meaning the data is huge but mostly static. In our case, the data is huge but also gets updated frequently. So, the question how Falcor works when the backend data gets updated frequently.

Answer (score 3):

If data held in client memory becomes stale due to its server-side representation changing (e.g. two separate users manipulating the same part of the graph) then you'll need some sort of server-push-to-client event stream thingy to notify the client of changes so it can keep its data cache fresh.

To my knowledge Falcor doesn't have any built-in hooks for this sort of thing. That doesn't mean Falcor can't be used for dynamic data; most MVC framework have this caveat. Just something to be aware of.